# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error when using Firebase mobile authentication on my physical device.
Looking for solutions I did the following:
1.Updated SHA1 in firebase console
2.I am using firebase Api and android N
3.I checked for play store updates and it shows that it is the latest version
Note: I am not using a emulator but a real device and it still is not working.

> 02-25 11:25:23.430 13164-13164/com.odetion.odetion W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
>   02-25 11:25:24.077 13164-13164/com.odetion.odetion W/OtpVerificationActivity: onVerificationFailed
>                                                                                 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdye.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdyf.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Comment: Is your device connected with Google Play Services.

Comment: Yes Google Play Services is connected in my device

Comment: Did you find the root cause issue or at least solution that let you move forward?

Answer (score 1):

As you error says:

```
Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.
```

So the problem is either your `package name` isn't correct or either your `SHA-1`. Make sure both are correct and try again.

Comment: I have already checked my SHA1 and package name and both are correct

Comment: If so, this error should not appear. So I strongly recommend you to check again. So, which one of that was the problem?

Comment: I have checked it like a million times and it is correct even deleted the app and linked it again to Firebase and still am getting the same error